# django ifchanged value before change

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I used `ifcahnged` as

```
{% for day in doctor.scheduled_by.all %}
   {% ifchanged day.start_day_time %}
      <span> {{ day }} </span>
      <span>{{ day.start_day_time }} AM - {{ day.end_day_time }} PM</span>
   {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

and the result is as

```
Saturday
5:00:00 AM - 14:30:00 PM

Friday
0:09:00 AM - 0:02:00 PM
```

I want something like

```
Saturday - Thursday
5:00:00 AM - 14:30:00 PM

Friday - Saturday
0:09:00 AM - 0:02:00 PM
```

:) (new to community).

**update**

Actually this is how my **models.py** is

```
class DaySchedulePattern(models.Model):
    week_day = models.ForeignKey(WeekDays, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_slot_duration = models.DurationField()
    start_day_time = models.DurationField()
    end_day_time = models.DurationField()
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        "account.Doctor", on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="scheduled_by"
    )
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: thanks for replay, just updated the question and that's how my model is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use django build-in [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date): `date`

assume `day` in your template is a DateTime in your code(which is not shown in your model), It needs add duration first.

```
{% for day in doctor.scheduled_by.all %}
   {% ifchanged day.start_day_time %}
      <span> {{ day }} </span> - <span> {{ day|add:day.end_day_time|date:'l' }}
      <span>{{ day.start_day_time }} AM - {{ day.end_day_time }} PM</span>
   {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could have a property `end_day` in `account.Doctor` for end day returning day value.

```
@property
def end_day(self):
   days, hours, minutes = end_day_time.days, end_day_time.hours, end_day_time.minutes
   return day.start_day_time + datetime.timedelta(days=<days>, hours=<hours>).day



{% for day in doctor.scheduled_by.all %}
   {% ifchanged day.start_day_time %}
      <span> {{ day }} - {{day.end_day}}</span>
      <span>{{ day.start_day_time }} AM - {{ day.end_day_time }} PM</span>
   {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```